# Saving and removing NSUserDefaults from one ViewController to another - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I'm having some trouble in Swift creating a bookmark list in a tableView using NSUserDefaults. The saving and displaying part I have but its the deleting a saved string and reloading the tableView from another view controller is where I have been stuck for a long time.

Basically, I am just trying to save a string with a button to another view controller inside a tableView. When button selected, save string to the tableView. When button deselected, remove that same string from the tableView.

**Bookmark View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class BookmarkController: UIViewController {
    var bookmark: String = "Hello World"

    @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        if myButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.grayColor() {
           myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
           favoritesList.append(bookmark)
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favoritesList, forKey:"favoritesList")
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }
    else if myButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.blueColor() {
           myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("favoritesList")
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()                       
        }

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favoritesList") != nil) {
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }else{
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    }
     }

}
```

**View Controller with tableView (keeps the data)**

```
import UIKit

var favoritesList = [String]()

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

      @IBOutlet var toDoListTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favoritesList") != nil {

         favoritesList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favoritesList") as! [String]

         }

      }

       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{       
           return favoritesList.count     
       }

       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

             cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
             cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
             cell.textLabel!.text = favoritesList[indexPath.row]
             return cell
            }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
            if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{
                favoritesList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favoritesList, forKey: "favoritesList")
                toDoListTable.reloadData()
             }

         override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
           toDoListTable.reloadData()
         }
     }
```

Comment: One recommendation, if you have `if (true) { set -> sync () } else { set -> sync () }` you should change this to `if (true) { set } else { set } sync ()` - cleaner code

Comment: don't know if this is really your problem, but one thing i noticed is that you are deleting the hole list? `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("favoritesList")` and not just the buttons value?

Comment: No need to force syncronize

Comment: @LeoDabus I set `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` everytime the button is hit. I feel like the tableView just isn't reloading after that for some reason.

Comment: You can delete it all. The problem it is something else

Comment: You should add your observer inside view did load, or put it inside view will appear and remove it inside view will disappear

Comment: Btw why would you need an observer for reloading table view?

Comment: The only case I had to use observer for reloading data was to reload the files list after asynchronous download

Comment: Think I was getting crazy confused. Thought if my the tableView was notified that the button was deselected, to then remove it from table and reloadData() in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the `BookmarkController` you are not populating the `favoritesList` like you do in the `SecondViewController`. You should load the `favoritesList` in viewDidLoad before manipulating it.

Comment: Yea, I tried this. I keep getting confused because if I have a bunch of strings stored in favoritesList and I load them all along with the current one i'm bookmarking, how do I manipulate the string Im currently working on. Is there a way in NSUserdefaults to check for a setObject that equals an exact value and then manipulate? I know you can ' if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favoritesList") != nil' but that just checks to see if there is anything in favoritesList and doesn't check if the current string is in favoritesList.

Comment: You could iterate thru the favoritesList array and find the string that you are currently working on. Then depending on whether you want to delete it or replace it you can either use removeObject or replaceObjectAtIndex as required and set the array back to the preference.